# Como habilitar/desabilitar dispositivos do windows 7 através de um .bat ou outro tipo de arquivo?

Tags: batch, windows-7

Preciso habilitar e desabilitar um dispositivo específico (gerenciador de dispositivos) com frequência, e fazer manualmente é muito chato. Acredito que com um arquivo .bat seja possível habilitar/desabilitar cada vez que eu executar. Vi que é possível com o DevCon, mas é muito empenho para pouca coisa. Agradeço se alguém souber alguma solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível desabilitar e habilitar dispositivos com o [DevManView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html) por linha de comando.

Para desativar um dispositivo pode fazer com o seguinte comando:

```
devmanview.exe /disable "Nome do Dispositivo"
```

Para habilitar:

```
devmanview.exe /enable "Nome do Dispositivo"
```

> O nome do dispositivo deve ser o mesmo que está no gerenciador de
>   dispositivos.
>
> Salve os arquivos .bat no diretório que está o executável
>   `devmanview.exe`, ou copie este para a System32.

[**Download DevManView**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/devmanview.zip)

Comment: Gostei muito dessa solução. Mas como eu faria um IF para verificar se o dispostivo esta ou não habilitado? Tem um exemplo?

Comment: O DevManView não oferece essa opção, porém se pode verificar se o dispositivo foi desabilitado ou habilitado pelo batch anteriormente com um arquivo auxiliar.